# What means endpoint?

Tags: protocol-theory, internet

I am reading about Network Socket.

`Network Socket is a one endpoint in a communication flow between two programs running over a network.`

I would like a better definition about `endpoint` I searched but that is not being obvious for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An endpoint is the beginning or end of something.  For example, if you call your friend on the telephone, the phones are the endpoints of the call path.

Comment: depends on the network and protocol layer referred to? about Socket, this refer to transport layer, because of "communication flow"?

Comment: I was going to say that it depends on the context. The "L7 endpoints" in the phone call example may very well be the two friends themselves.

Comment: Exactly, an endpoint reference is dependent on the context. The people are the endpoints of the conversation (layer-7), but I would consider the phones the endpoints of the call path (layer-4).